# Returning multiple assert messages in one test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, mstest, assert

Im running some tests on my code at the moment. My main test method is used to verify some data, but within that check there is a lot of potential for it to fail at any one point.

Right now, I've set up multiple `Assert.Fail` statements within my method and when the test is failed, the message I type is displayed as expected. However, if my method fails multiple times, it only shows the first error. When I fix that, it is only then I discover the second error.

None of my tests are dependant on any others that I'm running. Ideally what I'd like is the ability to have my failure message to display every failed message in one pass. Is such a thing possible?

As per the comments, here are how I'm setting up a couple of my tests in the method:

```
  private bool ValidateTestOne(EntityModel.MultiIndexEntities context)
  {
     if (context.SearchDisplayViews.Count() != expectedSdvCount)
        {
              Assert.Fail(" Search Display View count was different from what was expected");

        }
     if (sdv.VirtualID != expectedSdVirtualId)
        {
             Assert.Fail(" Search Display View virtual id was different from what was expected");

        }
     if (sdv.EntityType != expectedSdvEntityType)
        {
           Assert.Fail(" Search Display View entity type was different from what was expected");

        }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Without any relevant code, there's little more to say than "That's how it's supposed to work" and "Break up your test into smaller tests".

Comment: ... As @CodeCaster says, it's hard to comment. In lieu of code, you might want to read: ["*Is it OK to have multiple asserts in a single unit test?*"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7823/163789).

Comment: Updated with code sample

Comment: What framework do you use? NUnit or MsTest? I would not recommend using `Assert.Fail()` at all

Comment: You've got three `Assert.Fail()` calls which, in my view, should be split into three separate tests. Much cleaner to do three test methods, each of which use `Assert.AreEqual`, or `Assert.IsTrue`, etc. Assert.Fail just feels a bit wrong. Could be just me though.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a string/stringbuilder that holds all the fail messages, check for its length at the end of your code, and pass it into Assert.Fail? Just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

The NUnit test runner (assuming thats what you are using) is designed to break out of the test method as soon as anything fails.

So if you want *every* failure to show up, you need to break up your test into smaller, single assert ones. In general, you only want to be testing one thing per test *anyways*.

On a side note, using `Assert.Fail` like that isn't very semantically correct. Consider using the other built-in methods (like `Assert.Equals`) and only using `Assert.Fail` when the other methods are not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> None of my tests are dependent on any others that I'm running. Ideally
>   what I'd like is the ability to have my failure message to display
>   every failed message in one pass. Is such a thing possible?

It is possible only if you split your test into several smaller ones.

If you are afraid code duplication which is usually exists when tests are complex, you can use setup methods. They are usually marked by attributes:

- NUnit - [`SetUp`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setup&r=2.6.4),
- MsTest - [`TestInitialize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testinitializeattribute.aspx),
- XUnit - [constructor](https://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons#attributes).

The following code shows how your test can be rewritten:

```
public class HowToUseAsserts
{
    int expectedSdvCount = 0;
    int expectedSdVirtualId = 0;
    string expectedSdvEntityType = "";

    EntityModelMultiIndexEntities context;

    public HowToUseAsserts()
    {
        context = new EntityModelMultiIndexEntities();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Search_display_view_count_should_be_the_same_as_expected()
    {
        context.SearchDisplayViews.Should().HaveCount(expectedSdvCount);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Search_display_view_virtual_id_should_be_the_same_as_expected()
    {
        context.VirtualID.Should().Be(expectedSdVirtualId);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Search_display_view_entity_type_should_be_the_same_as_expected()
    {
        context.EntityType.Should().Be(expectedSdvEntityType);
    }
}
```

So your test names could provide the same information as you would write as messages:

[image]

> Right now, I've set up multiple Assert.Fail statements within my
>   method and when the test is failed, the message I type is displayed as
>   expected. However, if my method fails multiple times, it only shows
>   the first error. When I fix that, it is only then I discover the
>   second error.

This behavior is correct and many testing frameworks follow it.

I'd like to recommend stop using `Assert.Fail()` because it forces you to write specific messages for every failure. Common asserts provide good enough messages so you can replace you code with the following lines:

```
    // Act
    var context = new EntityModelMultiIndexEntities();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(expectedSdvCount, context.SearchDisplayViews.Count());
    Assert.Equal(expectedSdVirtualId, context.VirtualID);
    Assert.Equal(expectedSdvEntityType, context.EntityType);
```

But I'd recommend start using should-frameworks like [Fluent Assertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/) which make your code mere readable and provide better output.

```
    // Act
    var context = new EntityModelMultiIndexEntities();

    // Assert
    context.SearchDisplayViews.Should().HaveCount(expectedSdvCount);
    context.VirtualID.Should().Be(expectedSdVirtualId);
    context.EntityType.Should().Be(expectedSdvEntityType);
```